# Trigger method after react-rewards confetti

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web app where the user should be celebrated if he clicks a button. I have an onSuccess method that triggers the next section. At this point the confetti from react-rewards trigger (similar to react-dom-confetti) but it instantly go-ahead to onSuccess and closes the modal.
Did somebody know if the confetti element has kind of a variable which changes when the confetti has fallen down?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to properly answer your question without more context, a code sample would be helpful for example.

You could maybe delay the navigation / modal closing by using a delayed event handler like:

```
const myDelayedHandler = (rewardRef) => {

  // Start animation
  rewardRef.rewardMe();

  setTimeout(() => {
    closeModal();
  }, 500) // Delay close modal / next section for 0.5s
}
```

And if that does not answer your question, why not read the [source code?](https://github.com/thedevelobear/react-rewards/blob/master/src/components/Confetti.js)

Comment: Okay I've seen time outs but was not sure if it is used in business systems. Thanks for your help!